# ¿how open serialport COM Arduino on pc with Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, arduino

i wanna get data from SerialPort COM from Arduino. I'm using Windows 10. I developt an app on Nodejs, it works perfectly in my local network, but when i deployed my Nodejs App To Heroku i can't receive anything i got this log message from heroku console

```
2020-02-25T19:06:15.325036+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: No such file or directory, cannot open COM8
2020-02-25T19:06:15.325136+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2020-02-25T19:06:15.325252+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

code on server:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , datosconsulta = require('./routes/consultas')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');
//var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
var flash = require('connect-flash')
var serialPort = require("serialport");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;  
var server = app.listen(PORT, () => { //Start the server, listening on port 4000.
console.log("Aplicacion corriendo a través del puerto "+PORT);
})

var io = require('socket.io')(server); 

var serialPort = require("serialport");

   serial = new serialPort(COM8,{parser: new serialPort.parsers.Readline("\r\n"),"baudRate": 9600});    

      serial.on('open',function(err){

      if(err != null)
      {
      console.log("error no se puedo conectar el puerto COM");
      }

      else
      {
      console.log("Conexion USB lista");

              serial.on('data', function (data) {
              var readData += data.toString();
              console.log("dato serial" + readData);
               }
             });
      }
      });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The Heroku container does not have access to serial ports and that's why you get  "Error: No such file or directory, cannot open COM8"

Answer (score 0):

Your computer probably has a serial COM port that is likely connected to your Arduino. That is why it is working on localhost.

Your Heroku app instance does not have a serial COM port thus it cannot do serial communication.